# What are the mechanics of server side rendering and state management?

Tags: redux, state, server-side-rendering, vercel

I've been developing with React and Redux for years but always client side.

I understand the general philosophy of SSR and I can follow tutorials implementing SSR State management, but I feel like the concept doesn't sit well in my mind.

How does state management work server side? What can't I do (with regards to state) in SSR that I can do in CSR? What can I do but shouldn't? What are the general caveats and variations?

I feel like if I had a decent grasp on the implementation I'd have the mental freedom to run with it.

In this specific project I'm working with Vercel

Answer (score 0):

> What can't I do (with regards to state) in SSR that I can do in CSR?

The main difference between **SSR** and **CSR** for your state management is that for **SSR** you’ll need to **wait your async** change **before rendering** your page (or part of your page if you stream it).
While in **CSR** you can update your state and the UI as many as you want.